# Can't access HTTPS from my Android Emulator

Tags: android, https, react-native, proxy, android-emulator

I'm behind a corporate proxy and everything that access the internet needs a special configuration regarding Proxy. I'm on a CentOS 7, using CNTLMD to handle proxy tunneling, developing for mobile with React Native. And I'm using the Android Emulator provided by Android Studio.

I first noticed that my emulator can't access any HTTPS protocol when I tried to open Google in the Browser. Internally google redirects to HTTPS and I always get that "Connection Refused" error. Later (this week), trying to use Axios and Fetch to make HTTP/HTTPS requests, this has become a serious problem, since the APIs I'm trying to connect to are under the HTTPS protocol.

A friend of mine who is working in the same project but using Mac has no problems with HTTPS. I have also tried to start the emulator with the following commands:

```
emulator -avd myemulator -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

And

```
emulator -avd Marshmallow86 -http-proxy http://<network username>:<network password>@<ip>:<port>
```

And they do nothing.

I tried setting up HTTP and HTTPS proxy on Android Studio but this don't seem to be the way (and also didn't work).

**@edit**

I set the http_proxy on my host and started the emulator without parameters. Didn't work as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the software above that isn't android avd or androidstudio,
but it looks like a proxy or CA certificate problem.
Since the difference seems to be by OS, I would guess CA certificate first.

This android page has advice on using openssl from the command line to
explore that and consider importing certificates.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

This android page has current suggestions for proxy configurations:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Note, that the above instructions are updated for new features.
In the past I needed a proxy to a non-ssl appengine development server
which is slightly different from your problem but here's what I used:

For an SSL proxy, used the apache web server, and configured it to use SSL
by installing a self-signed certificate, then added a ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse 
in httpd.conf and a ProxyPass in the httpd-ssl.conf. 
    ProxyPass  /    http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Apache as an SSL proxy receives connections to https://127.0.0.1:443 and
passes them to http://127.0.0.1:8080

Then in the application, code that will be running in the emulator 
can use address
10.0.2.2 to use android subnet routing table to connect to the dev. OS localhost.